# How to set xml annotations dynamically?

Tags: java, xml, api, jaxb

So I've got a big excel sheet that has a bunch of labels with values attached to them, think Party_Name being the label with "IBM" being the value in that specific cell. I've read them all into a HashMap, with the key being the label and the value being the value of the cell (both of type String). Thing is, I want to be able to bind each as a XML tag so that it'll display in a web browser when I point it to the specific path of a Party. Is it possible to set these xml element dynamically because it'd a pain to statically make the 100+ tags? Oh, I've previously been using JAXB as well. So what I want is something like this

```
<Party_Name> IBM </Party_Name>
<id> 123456 </id>
...etc
```

Comment: Here is how it can be done using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html

Comment: That looks like that'd work I guess, is there anyway to do it without having to download additional software??